# SQL character delimited rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL column with the following values:

```
Col1
22;34;56;70
```

I need to be able to create a query that will return 4 rows from that i.e:

```
Col1
22
34
56
70
```

How would I split by `;`?

Comment: '22;34;56;70' is one value... Don't store data as ; separated items, you will only get lots of trouble if you do!

Comment: yeah it is. I will go ahead and remove it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table #t(id varchar(max))
insert into #t values('22;34;56;70')

 SELECT   
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT [id],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([id], ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  #t) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```